# TypeScript and CDK referring to stack itself

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, constructor, aws-cdk

I wanted to use Stack.formatArn() method inside my current Stack constructor. Wondering what's the difference between `this.formatArn()` and `cdk.Stack.of(this).formatArn()`; Doesn't this refers to the stack itself?

Thanks

Seems like the compiler doesn't complain both code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of a [Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html) instance, yes, the two methods are equivalent.

The [Stack.of](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#static-ofconstruct) static method traverses the [construct tree](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_tree), returning the first `Stack` instance it finds.  In the Stack constructor, it doesn't have to go anywhere to find a Stack:  `Stack.of(this) === this`.

A Stack's `formatArn` ARN-builder method is a simple wrapper around the [Arn.format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Arn.html#static-formatcomponents-stack) static method.  It conveniently uses the Stack's partition, account and region.

These are all equivalent ways of building an ARN within a stack's constructor:

```js
declare const components: ArnComponents

this.formatArn(components)
Stack.of(this).formatArn(components)
Arn.format(components, this)
Arn.format({ ...components, account: this.account, region: this.region })
```